# Nested Java Swagger @Operation config

Tags: java, swagger, openapi, swagger-codegen

Via swagger-annotations v2.1.5 dependency, I am trying to build below:

```
"x-amazon-apigateway-integration":{
    "type":"http",
    "httpMethod":"GET",
    "uri":"http://<DOMAIN>/api/hello-world",
    "responses":{
        "default":{
            "statusCode":200
        }
    }
}
```

Below Java code generates above JSON, except the "responses" tree. Can someone please suggest how can it be added in below Java code:

```
@Operation(extensions = {
        @io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.extensions.Extension(name = "x-amazon-apigateway-integration", properties = {
                @io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.extensions.ExtensionProperty(name = "type", value = "http"),
                @io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.extensions.ExtensionProperty(name = "httpMethod", value = "GET"),
                @io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.extensions.ExtensionProperty(name = "uri", value = "http://<DOMAIN>/api/hello-world")
        })
})
@GetMapping(value = "/hello-world")
public ResponseEntity<?> helloWorld() {
    return ResponseEntity.ok("Hello World");
}
```

pom.xml have the below 3 dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Please help if anyone can.

Comment: You need to add an `ExtensionProperty` for `responses`.

Comment: Hi Helen, I did @ExtensionProperty but I am not able to create nested extensions.

Answer (score 1):

Try below :

```
@ExtensionProperty(name = "response", value = "{\"default\":{\"statusCode\":200}", parseValue = true)
```

[Reference](https://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/v2.2.6/apidocs/io/swagger/v3/oas/annotations/extensions/ExtensionProperty.html#parseValue--)

Comment: you made my day, thanks!